# MonoGame Cross-Platform Conditional Compilation Symbol for Universal Windows Platform

Tags: c#, uwp, monogame

Just trying to find the correct Cross-Platform conditional compilation symbol for UWP applications. If found this thread:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/55657/monogame-cross-platform-conditional-compilation-symbols

but it doesn't seem to list the UWP apps.

Answer (score 0):

the answer to this question is:

```
#if WINDOWS_UAP
    using Windows.Storage;
#endif
```